# iTunes downloads through manager

Tags: itunes, network, data-transfer, internet, itunes-store

When I download iTunes apps, music, etc.. content, the download speed fluctuates a lot and usually falls to around 64kbps. This is very impractical and time-consuming.
Whereas, if I download other files through my browser, I get 512 kbps (my actual connection speed. I use a broadband connected with a cable, not WiFi).

So, is there a way/software, which could capture/log the download link when iTunes starts the download, so I could copy that into my download manager and download at full speeds?
Maybe an IP connection logger, or firewall?
I would have to start the download via iTunes first though, since I need the validated, purchased app file.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple causes which causes your iTunes to be slow.

- An old version of iTunes. Make sure you've the latest version as Apple constantly improves the software.
- The Apple TV feature. This feature scans your iTunes library constantly. You can simple turn it off in your preferences.
- Shared Libraries. Find in your preferences this option and turn it off. Sharing items demands bandwidth as well. You might gain a bit if you turn this off.
- Genius is constantly connecting, comparing and matching your songs. It's designed to be a light weight feature, but in the end, it adds up and takes away the speed of other features like "Downloads".

It [looks like](http://www.killertechtips.com/2012/04/20/increase-itunes-download-speed/) you can add iTunes to a download manager (Windows only), so maybe if you provide me your download manager, I can find a way to add iTunes?

Comment: He's talking about bandwidth slowing down; this isn't because of anything iTunes is doing. Some ISPs throttle downloads from Apple at certain times of the day; that's the case with my current ISP.

Comment: It's a public secret downloading with iTunes is slower then downloading in your browser. Many users suffer from this. And in my opinion, it's because there are that many background processes (like Genius, TV, Sharing,...)

Comment: Sorry, I disagree. When I'm not throttled, iTunes downloads use all my available incoming bandwidth. In fact, I've never heard anyone say this before (and I do know a bit about iTunes).

Comment: I'm using the latest version of iTunes - 11.0.1. No, I'm not using any other iTunes features ( I've switched off TV, Podcasts, Genius, Match). No Shared Libraries are enabled. I'll try using Internet Download Manager and see how that goes.

Comment: Also, AFAIK my ISP doesn't throttle my iTunes downloads.

Comment: Alright! Thanks, @Michiel, it works! I just have to add the IPA file extension to IDM's list and it captures the iTunes download instantly, and downloads at full speed. The purchase info and icon aren't preserved, though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, Apple won't let you do that, in part because of the way they cache the downloads.